# Return hierarchical parents in SQL Server function

Tags: sql-server, function, parent, temp-tables, hierarchical

SQL Server query

```
WITH hierarchical AS (
        SELECT ModelId, ParentId
        FROM [dbo].Models] 
        WHERE ModelId = 142
        UNION ALL
        SELECT parent.ModelId, parent.ParentId
        FROM [dbo].[Models] parent 
        INNER JOIN hierarchical child ON child.ParentId = parent.ModelId
)
SELECT * FROM hierarchical
```

return this

```
ModelId   ParentId
142       141
141       136
136       135
135       10
10        0
```

Need this query in SQL function

```
DECLARE @TempModelParents table (ModelId INT, ParentId INT)

INSERT INTO @TempModelParents 
SELECT ModelId, ParentId
FROM [dbo].[Models] 
WHERE ModelId = 142
UNION ALL
SELECT parent.ModelId, parent.ParentId
FROM [dbo].[Models] parent 
INNER JOIN @TempModelParents child ON child.ParentId = parent.ModelId

SELECT * FROM  @TempModelParents
```

But returns this

```
ModelId   ParentId
142       141
```

How can use this query in SQL function and return all parents

Comment: Just parametrise the query you have, and put it in the function. Also, nesure that said function is an **inline** table value function, not a multi-line table value function (which you appear to be designing). You're missing the rCTE in your function, so of course it isn't recursing.

Comment: I don't follow your point (apart from it can't be, because there's no `CREATE FUNCTION`)